# Python package that implements TFTP, FTP, SFTP servers

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, sftp, tftp

I'm using [tftpy](http://tftpy.sourceforge.net/) to create TFTP server in my Python program and it works amazing. However, I need to have other flavors of servers: TFTP, FTP, SFTP. What package may I use that supports all of them?

Comment: The main common thing of these protocols is "ftp" in their name. Apart from that these are completely different protocols, so you might need to use separate packages for each of these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every protocol needs its own implementation, for example:

- TFTP: [TFTPy](http://tftpy.sourceforge.net/)
- FTP: [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html)
- SFTP:  [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/), [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/api/twisted.conch.ssh.filetransfer.FileTransferClient.html)

However, if you insist on a single package to rule them all, and don't mind getting your hands a bit dirty, [PycURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) is for you:

> **PycURL** is a Python interface to libcurl. PycURL can be used to fetch
> objects identified by a URL from a Python program, similar to the
> urllib Python module. PycURL is mature, very fast, and supports a lot
> of features.
>
> **libcurl** is a free and easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library,
> supporting FTP, FTPS, HTTP, HTTPS, SCP, SFTP, TFTP, TELNET, DICT,
> LDAP, LDAPS, FILE, IMAP, SMTP, POP3 and RTSP. libcurl supports SSL
> certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based
> upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic, Digest,
> NTLM, Negotiate, Kerberos4), file transfer resume, http proxy
> tunneling and more!

For code examples with `PycURL`, check [here](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/tree/master/examples) and [here](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/tree/master/tests).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm inclined to use several packages since I'm implementing interface to them anyway